# Caliburn.Micro when setting VM to inherit Screen, overrides title field in View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

If I have a ViewModel like so:

```
 public class ViewModel : IPropertyChangeBase, IViewModel
 {
 }
```

The "Title" property I set in the xaml of the view it's bound to properly shows.

If I have the ViewModel inherit from Screen instead what shows up in the title is the complete type name of the ViewModel, like "MarksProject.ViewModels.ViewModel." This shows up on the window's title.

```
 //View Title property being overriden.
 public class ViewModel : Screen, IViewModel
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Screen defines a property DisplayName that Caliburn.Micro uses to automatically populate headers. Just set that in the constructor like this:

```
public ViewModel() {
    this.DisplayName = "MyTitle";
}
```

And you'll have your title back - and saved a Property in the process ;)

Comment: I often like to store Model objects inside the ViewModel and wrap it's fields inside ViewModel properties. It's really bad that Conducotrs try to overwrite it if I want to wrap the name inside the DisplayName property. I think IHaveDisplayName interface should only have had a getter and no setter.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to call virtual members (`DisplayName`) from a constructor as in @T045T's answer. This is a safer way:

```
public class ViewModel : Screen
{
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get { return "View Title"; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Note that `set { }` is needed to avoid `Mode=TwoWay` binding errors.